# how do I restrict a value in an xml element to have a defined type?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to validate this xml document, with a type for the age field that can be re-used in other elements:

```
<Person>
  <name>joe</name>
  <age>254</age>
</Person>
```

The XSD file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Age">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
        <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
        <xs:maxInclusive value="100" />
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="Age"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

fails with "Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'age' To A(n) 'type Definition' Component."
If I change the type="Age" to type="xs:integer" to get the schema usable, the XML document passes when it should fail because the age is out of range.

The document

```
<Age>254</Age>
```

correctly fails because it is being checked against the Age type.

How can I get the person element to validate its age field against the Age type? (This is a toy example; the actual type represented by Age is more complex. And yes, the xsd still doesn't work if the typename is "ageRange" to be distinct from the field name "age".)

----- EDIT ------

[XSD](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#Complex_Type_Definitions) contains the example

```
<xs:complexType name="PurchaseOrderType">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element name="shipTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
   <xs:element ref="comment" minOccurs="0"/>
   <xs:element name="items"  type="Items"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="orderDate" type="xs:date"/>
 </xs:complexType>
```

so the question is how to get the type "USAddress" or "Age" to resolve when it is the type of named element content? Defining them under the same root schema should be sufficient.

Comment: Don't you want a ToyAge and a PersonAge where a person age is 0 to 100 and a toy age is 0 to 1000?

Comment: This is not about the age of anything, it's just a simple example to illustrate the use case of defining a reusable type.  Pretend it is "emailAddress" - that's the same  whether it's a person or a company.

Comment: Then what is the issue?  If you are going to compare a a value to determine it is in a range of numbers than it has to be a number.  Do you really want to make the age type dynamic and sometime be a string and other times a number.  It can't be both and also be able to test if it is between 0 and 100.  You can't have your cake and pie too.

Comment: What is your suggestion for correcting the example? Age is a number (xs:integer) always, what in the example indicates that I want it to ever be a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make age a simple type

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="Age">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                <xs:maxInclusive value="100" />
            </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="Person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="age" type="Age"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```